# Is it possible to get the Cursive Plugin installed with Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, clojure, cursive

I am currently starting my first project that will use Clojure to write an Android App using Android Studio.

My idea was to install the [Cursive Plugin](https://cursive-ide.com/) as this Plugin is available for IntelliJ Community Edition on which Android Studio is based.

Unfortunately my (maybe naive?) approach to just go to Settings -> Plugins -> Browse repositories ... and search for "Cursive" did not show any hits.

Is there any other way to install the [Cursive Plugin](https://cursive-ide.com/) with Android Studio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download it directly from IDEA repository:
[IDEA repository](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/8090)
Choose your version of IDEA and click download. Then follow this [user guide](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/installing-plugin-from-disk.html)

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks for your help.