# How do I use Clojure in Android Studio using Graclj?

Tags: android, gradle, clojure, android-gradle-plugin, graclj

My ultimate goal is to be able to write Clojure apps for Android, using Android Studio and Cursive. I started with leiningen but found out that it is a build system that is independent of what Andoid Studio uses ie Gradle. So I tried leiningen with Intellij, but couldn't get Android deploys to work except from the command line. Since I wanted to integrate with Android Studio, I decided to try Graclj: https://github.com/graclj/graclj which is a Gradle plugin for Clojure.

I can get the Graclj tutorial running in Android Studio, as per this guide:
https://github.com/graclj/learning-graclj/tree/learning-0.1.0

However:

- Graclj expects the Clojure src and built classes and jars to be in the root project
- Android Studio expects src and classes to be in the app subproject
- After the tutorial I end up with separate Gradle build tasks for Graclj and Android Studio but I don't know how to integrate them

So, can anyone suggest a way that I can hook into Andoid Studio's build process?

- Do I need to change some settings to the Graclj plugin to do this? If so, how?
- Do I need to change some Android Studio plugin settings?
- Do I need to add/change something in the Gradle build scripts?
- Am I heading down a dead end?  ;-)

I have looked at the Android Studio build process: http://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html
but I don't know enough about Gradle to know what I'm supposed to be doing here.

If I need to supply any more info, just ask.

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortuantely, I don't have any Android (let alone Android Studio) experience. However, I'll do my best to answer based on Gradle/Graclj knowledge.

Graclj does not require you to use the root project. You can apply the plugin(s) in any of the projects that you have in your build. However, I don't know how well a model-based plugin like Graclj will work with the "traditional" Android plugin. You could try [the "experimental" one](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental) that's using the model approach, though there's a decent chance that it won't be compatible unless there's one that works with Gradle 2.12.

Alternatively, you might be able to add a dependency to the Android app project on the JAR produced by Graclj (which you may still want to put in a project besides the root). Not sure if there's a very good way to do this (haven't tried myself).

```
dependencies {
   // my-other-proj being whichever one you use Graclj in
   compile project(':my-other-proj')
}
```

Or maybe you would need to add it to a configuration first in the `my-other-proj` to interop with traditional plugins:

```
artifacts {
   archives createMainJar
}
```

It is possible that you're at a dead end (for now). Graclj is very new, so this stuff should all be possible eventually.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I looked at the experimental plugin,but it only supports up to Gradle 2.10. I tried adding the Clojure to another subproject, and it builds with "mainAotJar" task, but, when I add a reference to the jar in the `build.gradle` file  as: `artifacts { archives file('/build/jars/main/aotJar/main.jar') }` I get an error: `Error:com.android.dx.cf.iface.ParseException: class name (learning/graclj) does not match path (aotJar/learning/graclj.class)`. Also, I don't know how to auto-build the jar,I have to invoke the `mainAotJar` Gradle task manually. Any Ideas?

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately I'm not really sure what's going on there. You may be better off trying Clojuresque for now until Graclj and the experimental plugin mature more.

Comment: Ok, no problem. I've tried Clojuresque but it uses the Java plugin which conflicts with the Android plugin. If you'd like to look at this further in future, or at what Android Studio is doing in more detail, contact me and I'll be happy to help out where I can. I'd really like to use Clojure in Android Studio as Emacs is so limited compared to modern IDEs